# Mysql - Select highest by colomn

Tags: mysql, sql, select, unique

Feels like this must have been already answered, but I've been looking for a solution for weeks now for no avail.
Possible I just don't have the right wording for my issue - apologize.

I have a table (which is the results of another select) that (for the sake of the argument contains two columns:

```
Name    Salary
Jake     6k
Stephan  8k
Jake     7k
Stephan  5k
```

Now I want another select to narrow down the table to unique names while keeping only the highest values of Salary:

```
Name   Salary
Jake     7k
Stephan  8k
```

Comment: select name,max(salary) from table1 group by name

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `group by` clause on the name:

```
SELECT   name, MAX(salary)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: It's a step, but it leaves me with multiple values under the same names.

Comment: @user2993884 With a `group by` clause? That doesn't seem right. Can you share an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with such a query?

Comment: Actually, it worked! The issue was my table has way more columns than what I used for an example (cant paste the real table). Once I narrowed it down to 2 columns group by worked. Thanks for the quick reply!